# How to delete few files from zip in bash?

Tags: bash

In my zip archive I have many txt files. Some of them have names ending on `_temp_file.txt`.
I know I can delete files from my zip archive with `zip -d` command, but how do I remove all files that have that ending? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the command:

```
zip -d archive.zip "*_temp_file.txt"
```

that should remove anything ending with `_temp_file.txt` from the archive.